# Angular ng-model on label ignored

Tags: angularjs, label

I work with an Angular 1.5.5 application. I want to display a value (selectedRol.activities[0]) in a form. The value shows, the ng-show works also but the ng-model is ignored. Adding the attribute value="{{selectedRol.activities[0]}}" makes no difference.

I expect the output to be

Algemeen Leiding en Coördinatie
irData.Werkzaamheid1 = Algemeen Leiding en Coördinatie

but I get

Algemeen Leiding en Coördinatie
irData.Werkzaamheid1 =

```
                     <label
                            ng-show="selectedRol.activities.length === 1"
                            ng-model="irData.Werkzaamheid1"
                            ng-bind="selectedRol.activities[0]">
                    </label>
                    irData.Werkzaamheid1 = {{irData.Werkzaamheid1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ng-model in label element. Ng-model is used for inputs.

Instead, use ng-bind:

```
<label ng-show="selectedRol.activities.length === 1"
ng-bind="irData.Werkzaamheid1">
</label>
```

or as expression:

```
<label ng-show="selectedRol.activities.length === 1">
{{irData.Werkzaamheid1}}
</label>
```

Working plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tRpHueR08XxywIYY3OX3?p=preview)